# Gazebo 4 Installation Help

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to install Gazebo 4.0 on a different computer alongside ROS Indigo. I already removed Gazebo 2.2.2 that came with ROS. I saw on the tutorial page that in order to make Gazebo 4 work with ROS, I need to first "Add the osrfoundation repository to your sources list.". Does anyone know exactly what that step entails (i.e. what terminal commands to run)? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7008/gazebo-4-installation-help/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You have the step-by-step instructions detailed in [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install&ver=4.0&cat=get_started).

In a nutshell:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'

wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gazebo4
```

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-09-12**:
Thank you.